# Create soap request

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I've tried to serialize an object with XmlSerializer and SoapFormatter but i can't get the output to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Login xmlns="http://www.myfirm.com/2010/core/ConnectTypes">
  <UserLogin>
    <UserName>User</UserName>
    <Password>PW</Password>
    <Mandant>1</Mandant>
  </UserLogin>
</Login>

 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My classes:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class UserLoginType
{

    private string userNameField;

    private string passwordField;

    private int mandantField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.userNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return this.passwordField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.passwordField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Mandant
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mandantField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mandantField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class LoginType
{

    private object itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("LoginToken", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("UserLogin", typeof(UserLoginType))]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

To Log the SoapRequest try MessageInspector or enable the Logging in Web.Config for Web Service.

Comment: For what do i need to log the soap request?!?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you do not have to serialize our objects way like that.
You should add the Web-Reference via WSDL-url, and invoke methods of the service by the generated proxy class

Comment: Unfortunately there's no WSDL file.